# How make custom dataset for classification task when the class is folder name using Pytorch?

Tags: classification, pytorch

The problem is dataloader is returning the wrong class for correspond image?
for example if I print the class_to_idx from the train_loader, when batch size is 1I was expecting to get one class per batch, but currently it’s returning all the classes which is 15 classes per image.

In this case, the classes are folder class (all images exist in one folder belongs to one class)

snippet is here:(this is a function to return the class from the folder name dir)

```
import os
def find_classes(dir):   # Finds the class folders in a dataset, dir (string): Root directory path.

        classes = [d.name for d in os.scandir(dir) if d.is_dir()]
        classes.sort()
        class_to_idx = {classes[i]: i for i in range(len(classes))}
        return classes, class_to_idx
```

here is the main snippet for create a custom dataset and dataloder
def main():

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):    

    def __init__(self, image_paths, classes, class_to_id):  

        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.transforms = transforms.ToTensor() 
        classes, class_to_id = find_classes('D:/Neda/Echo_View_Classification/avi_images/')
        self.classes = classes
        self.class_to_idx = class_to_idx

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        image = Image.open(self.image_paths[index])
        t_image = image.convert('L')
        t_image = self.transforms(t_image)    

        class_to_idx = self.class_to_idx

        return t_image, class_to_idx, self.image_paths[index]

    def __len__(self): 

        return len(self.image_paths)


folder_data = glob.glob("D:\\Neda\\Echo_View_Classification\\avi_images\\*\\*.png") # no augmnetation
#numpy.savetxt('distribution_class.csv', numpy.c_[folder_data], fmt=['%s'], comments='', delimiter = ",")                    

 #split these path using a certain percentage
len_data = len(folder_data)
print("count of dataset: ", len_data)

split_1 = int(0.6 * len(folder_data))
split_2 = int(0.8 * len(folder_data))

folder_data.sort()

train_image_paths = folder_data[:split_1]
print("count of train images is: ", len(train_image_paths)) 
numpy.savetxt('im_training_path_1.csv', numpy.c_[train_image_paths], fmt=['%s'], comments='', delimiter = ",")                    


valid_image_paths = folder_data[split_1:split_2]
print("count of validation image is: ", len(valid_image_paths))
numpy.savetxt('im_valid_path_1.csv', numpy.c_[valid_image_paths], fmt=['%s'], comments='', delimiter = ",")     


test_image_paths = folder_data[split_2:]
print("count of test images is: ", len(test_image_paths)) 
numpy.savetxt('im_testing_path_1.csv', numpy.c_[test_image_paths], fmt=['%s'], comments='', delimiter = ",")                    

classes = ['1_PLAX_1_PLAX_full',
  '1_PLAX_2_PLAX_valves',
  '1_PLAX_4_PLAX_TV',
  '2_PSAX_1_PSAX_AV',
  '2_PSAX_2_PSAX_LV',
  '3_Apical_1_MV_LA_IAS',
  '3_Apical_2_A2CH',
  '3_Apical_3_A3CH',
  '3_Apical_5_A5CH',
  '4_A4CH_1_A4CH_LV',
  '4_A4CH_2_A4CH_RV',
  '4_Subcostal_1_Subcostal_heart',
  '4_Subcostal_2_Subcostal_IVC',
  'root_5_Suprasternal',
  'root_6_OTHER']


class_to_idx = {'1_PLAX_1_PLAX_full': 0,
  '1_PLAX_2_PLAX_valves': 1,
  '1_PLAX_4_PLAX_TV': 2,
  '2_PSAX_1_PSAX_AV': 3,
  '2_PSAX_2_PSAX_LV': 4,
  '3_Apical_1_MV_LA_IAS': 5,
  '3_Apical_2_A2CH': 6,
  '3_Apical_3_A3CH': 7,
  '3_Apical_5_A5CH': 8,
  '4_A4CH_1_A4CH_LV': 9,
  '4_A4CH_2_A4CH_RV': 10,
  '4_Subcostal_1_Subcostal_heart': 11,
  '4_Subcostal_2_Subcostal_IVC': 12,
  'root_5_Suprasternal': 13,
  'root_6_OTHER': 14}


train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_image_paths, class_to_idx, classes)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

valid_dataset = CustomDataset(valid_image_paths,  class_to_idx, classes)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)


test_dataset = CustomDataset(test_image_paths, class_to_idx, classes)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)  

dataLoaders = {
        'train': train_loader,
        'valid': valid_loader,
         'test': test_loader,
        }
```

Comment: Please, specify why `ImageFolder` is not suitable...

Answer (score 0):

I think [ImageFolder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) from torchvision.datasets will help you in loading your data.

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I already have been used that link (ImageFolder) to create my own dataset, and couldn't get much information to solve my problem.